# How to Request a File from FTP Using Today's Date as part of Filename?

Tags: vb.net

We have a service that provides several files per day for pickup.  Each file is appended with today's date and the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds stamp of the time the file was created.

Our goal is to download all files for a given day regardless of the time stamp.  I've set the following variable:

```
Dim remoteFile As String = "/datafeed/sdlookup-total-" & DateTime.Today.Year.ToString 
& "-" & DateTime.Today.Month.ToString("0#") & "-" & DateTime.Today.Day.ToString("0#") & 
".csv.zip"
```

When I run the console application, I receive a HTTP 550 file not found because the files on the FTP all have the timestamp after the day e.g.

```
sdlookup-total-2013-07-27_02_15_00_272.csv.zip
```

The Module is as follows:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.WebClient

' This module when run will download the file specified and save it to the local path as defined.
Module Module1
Dim Today As Date = Now()
' Change the value of localFile to the desired local path and filename
 Dim localFile As String = "C:\ForeclosureFile\sdlookoup-total-" & Today.Year.ToString & "-" & 
 Today.Month.ToString("0#") & "-" & Today.Day.ToString("0#") & ".csv.zip"
' Change the value of remoteFile to the desired filename
 Dim remoteFile As String = "/datafeed/sdlookup-total-" & Today.Year.ToString & "-" & 
 Today.Month.ToString("0#") & "-" & Today.Day.ToString("0#") & ".csv.zip"
 Const host As String = "ftp://Datafeed.foreclosure.com"
 Const username As String = "sdlookup"
 Const pw As String = "ourpass"
 Dim strDownLoadTemplate = "sdlookup-total-" & Today.Year.ToString & "-" & Today.Month.ToString
 ("0#") & "-" & Today.Day.ToString("0#") & ".csv.zip"
 Dim strCleanFileForDTS As String
 Dim strLocalZipFile = "C:\ForeclosureFile\ForeclosureFull.zip"
 Dim strLocalCSVFile = "C:\ForeclosureFile\Foreclosurefull.csv"

 Sub Main()
    Dim URI As String = host + remoteFile
    Dim req As FtpWebRequest = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), FtpWebRequest)
    req.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, pw)

    req.KeepAlive = False
    req.UseBinary = True
    req.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

    Using response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = CType(req.GetResponse, 
    System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
        Using responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            Using fs As New IO.FileStream(localFile, IO.FileMode.Create)
                Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
                Dim read As Integer = 0
                Do
                    read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                Loop Until read = 0
                responseStream.Close()
                fs.Flush()
                fs.Close()
            End Using
            responseStream.Close()
        End Using
        response.Close()
    End Using
    Dim zipPath As String = "C:\ForeclosureFile\"
    Dim extractPath As String = "C:\ForeclousreFile"

    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)

End Sub

Sub ProcessFile()

    'Downloaded file
    Dim oFile As System.IO.File
    Dim oRead As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim strLocalCSVFile As String = "C:\ForeclosureFile\sdlookoup-total-" & 
    DateTime.Today.Year.ToString & "-" & DateTime.Today.Month.ToString("0#") & "-" & 
    DateTime.Today.Day.ToString("0#") & ".csv"
    Dim strCleanFileForDTS As String = "C:\ForeclosureFile\ForDTS\sdlookoup-total-" & 
    DateTime.Today.Year.ToString & "-" & DateTime.Today.Month.ToString("0#") & "-" & 
    DateTime.Today.Day.ToString("0#") & ".csv"
    Dim LineIn As String
    'Dim Fields() As String

    'New File
    Dim oNewFile As System.IO.File
    Dim oWrite As System.IO.StreamWriter

    oWrite = File.CreateText(localFile & strCleanFileForDTS)

    oRead = File.OpenText(localFile & strLocalCSVFile)

    '        strLocalCSVFile()

    While oRead.Peek <> -1
        'While oRead.
        LineIn = oRead.ReadLine()
        'Fixes file problem
        oWrite.WriteLine(Replace(LineIn, """", "", 1))
    End While

    oRead.Close()
    oWrite.Close()
End Sub

Sub FTPFileDownload(strtFetchFile As String, PathToSave As String)

    Dim myFtpWebRequest As FtpWebRequest
    Dim myFtpWebResponse As FtpWebResponse
    Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter
    Dim strFullPathandFile As String

    strFullPathandFile = PathToSave & strtFetchFile


    myFtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://Datafeed.foreclosure.com/datafeed/" & 
    strtFetchFile)

    myFtpWebRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("sdlookup", "ohpaiH1b")

    myFtpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
    myFtpWebRequest.UseBinary = True
    myFtpWebRequest.UsePassive = True


    myFtpWebResponse = myFtpWebRequest.GetResponse()

    PathToSave = "D:\test.zip"

    myStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(PathToSave)
    myStreamWriter.Write(New StreamReader(myFtpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd)

    myStreamWriter.Close()

    '  litResponse.Text = myFtpWebResponse.StatusDescription

    myFtpWebResponse.Close()


 End Sub

 Public Sub DownloadFiles(ByVal Wildcard As String)
    Wildcard = "sdlookup-total-*.csv.zip"
    Dim Files As String() = GetFiles(Wildcard)
    For Each file As String In Files
        DownloadFile(file)
    Next
 End Sub
End Module
```

How should I modify the above module so that all files containing sdlookup-total-"Today'sDate".csv.zip regardless of timestamp are downloaded each time the module is executed?

Comment: I'm not much of a vb.net person, but I wonder: Have you tried using a glob `sdlookup-total-2013-07-27*.zip`?  Or, can you get a directory listing and determine which files on the server match the first part of the pattern, and explicitly fetch those?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Please see the revised module code.  How would I obtain a directory listing per your comment?

Comment: FTP Directory listing howto in C# from microsoft's website, courtsey of google.  I recognize you're VB.net, but most of the runtime library is the same between C# and VB.net.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx